# is there a way to maximize the limit of Retry for Kafka listener in case of exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

i am using a spring boot app where the kafka consumer is consuming messages and saving into Hbase.

in case of any exception while reading the message from kafka topic how to limit the retry mechanism in case of batch listner. i have used the below kafka configuration but it is retrying for infinite time.

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootStrapServer);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, gropuId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecordSize);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    return props;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, byte[]> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, byte[]> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        factory.setBatchErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler());
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
        return factory;
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to not use a plain consumer for this https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/hbase.html

Comment: A normal KafkaConsumer does not have any config which can define the Maximum times a consumer can retry. Hence, you need to use the specific HBase Sink Connector in order to read the data from your Kafka to the HBase.

Comment: see here it seems `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` doesn't have retry config https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1382